# insert multiple line using shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I wanted to insert this lines of code before line number 1 inside the `package.json` is there any chance that can help me with this problem?

```bash
$ sed -i "1 i\
"scripts": {
  "dev": "yarn tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch"
}," package.json
```

I tried to do a research but it wont fix the problem, btw I am new to shell script.

Comment: Don't use sed for manipulating json, use jq

Comment: `jq '.scripts = {dev: "yarn ..."}' package.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json package.json`.

Comment: You aren't trying to add lines to a file; you are trying to add a key/value pair to an existing JSON object.

Comment: Paste your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `"` for `sed` command and have `"` in your text you are inserting.

do it like:

```
$ echo hi > package.json

$ cat package.json
hi

$ sed -i '1i"scripts": {\
  "dev": "yarn tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch"\
},' package.json

$ cat package.json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "yarn tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch"
},
hi
```

remember don't add any extra space after back slashes `\`

Comment: Perhaps a HERE-document would be easier to read?